# Add a space after commas in a string only if it doesn't exist in R

Tags: r, regex, string, gsub

For instance I have

```
a=c("Jack and Jill,went up the, hill,to,fetch a pail,of, water")
```

and I'm trying to do is add space after comma if and only if the comma is followed by an alphabet
such that my Output would look like this

```
 "Jack and Jill, went up the, hill, to, fetch a pail, of, water"
```

This is what I have tried

```
gsub("/,(?![ ])/, ", " ",a)
```

but doesn't give me desired result.
Any help would be much appreciated. THANKS

Comment: `gsub(",(?!\\s)",", ",a,perl=TRUE)` Or also `gsub(",(?=[A-Za-z])",", ",a,perl=TRUE)`.

Comment: This command even worked even if the case of numbers for eg. .....  a=c("my address,is, plot no 3,2nd street, lake cross, nz")....Much thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `gsub` to match a comma (`,`) followed by any letter (`([A-Za-z])`) captured as a group and then replace it with `,` followed by a space and the backreference of that captured group (`\\1`)

```
gsub(",([A-Za-z])", ", \\1", a)
#[1] "Jack and Jill, went up the, hill, to, fetch a pail, of, water"
```

Or use `[[:alpha:]]`

```
gsub(",([[:alpha:]])", ", \\1", a)
#[1] "Jack and Jill, went up the, hill, to, fetch a pail, of, water"
```

Comment: The `[A-z]` is a misleading character class. People believe it matches letters only, but [it is not so](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29771926/3832970).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  Thanks, I was not aware about that.  One time when I used `[A-Za-z]` somebody commented that it is much easier to do `[A-z]`.  Should have checked it.  Thanks for enligtening me

Comment: The problem is that this wrong pattern is used even [in some Web help](http://stat545.com/block022_regular-expression.html).